# jquery.Gantt days and dates have stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gantt-chart

I am using this awesome [plugin](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView) for creating a Gantt Chart using jQuery.

Now I have incorporated it into my site and the weekends and dates have flipped out, I am not sure if it is because of some of the other scripts I am running or if I have configured incorrectly, I am running [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) with it's usual dependencies (all scripts can be seen in demo).

Basically the weekends have started to shift 2 days along for every task on the chart, and the dates in the header are also off.

To see a full demo please see this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a4hw92/2/)**.

If you are experiencing trouble viewing gantt chart please adjust slider width to be smaller:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#ganttChart").ganttView({
            data: ganttData,
            slideWidth: 600
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It was the Foundation `box-sizing` defaults that were messing with the chart.

All I had to do was add this to the gantt.View css file.

```
.ganttview *, /* Override Foundation box-sizing properties */
.ganttview:before,
.ganttview:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Please check out this updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a4hw92/3/)**.